# $\lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}‎\frac{‎\Vert ‎x+ty‎\Vert‎^2-‎\Vert ‎x‎\Vert‎^2‎}{‎2t‎}=‎\| ‎x\|‎\cdot‎\lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}‎\frac{\| x+ty\| -\| x\|}{t}$?

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\| \cdot \|)$ be a normed space. Define $$‎‎‎\rho '_{‎\pm‎}(x,y)=\lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}‎\frac{‎\Vert ‎x+ty‎\Vert‎^2 -‎\Vert ‎x‎\Vert‎^2‎‎}{‎2t‎}.$$ How can prove the following? $$‎‎‎\rho '_{‎\pm‎}(x,y)=‎\| ‎x\|‎‎\cdot‎‎  ‎\lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}‎\frac{\| x+ty\| -\| x\|}{t}.$$

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a^2-b^2=(A+b)(a-b)$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$,
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho’_{\pm}(x,y)&=&\lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}\frac{\|x+ty\|+\|x\|}{2}\cdot\frac{\|x+ty\|-\|x\|}{t}\cr
&=&\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\frac{\|x+ty\|+\|x\|}{2}\cdot\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\frac{\|x+ty\|-\|x\|}{t}\cr
&=&\frac{\|x+0\cdot y\|+\|x\|}{2}\cdot\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\frac{\|x+ty\|-\|x\|}{t}\cr
&=&\|x\|\lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}\frac{\|x+ty\|-\|x\|}{t}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$‎\lVert ‎x+ty‎\rVert‎^2 -‎\lVert ‎x‎\rVert‎^2 =\left( ‎\lVert ‎x+ty‎\rVert -‎\lVert ‎x‎\rVert‎ \right)\left( ‎\lVert ‎x+ty‎\rVert‎+‎\lVert ‎x‎\rVert‎ \right)$$

and $$\lim_{t \to 0} \left( ‎\lVert ‎x+ty‎\rVert‎+‎\lVert ‎x‎\rVert‎ \right) = 2 \lVert x \rVert$$